# Как правильно распределять запросы по микросервисам?

Tags: golang, очередь, rabbitmq, микросервисы, apache-kafka

Допустим в качестве брокера запросов к микросервисам использую Кафка или Rabbit или что то другое.
Пока выбираю что использовать.

Но я не понимаю на основании чего брокеры знают каким именно сервисам нужно ставить запросы в очередь?
Т.е. например идет оформление заказа , запрашиваются данные от сервиса доставки о доступных способах доставки и сервис склада проверяет наличие.
А еще нужно при этом проверить, что пользователь авторизован.

Брокеры сообщений Кафка или Rabbit  самостоятельно решать какие сервисы вызывать не могут , да и не должны.

Жестко указывать в слое API какие сервисы должны быть вызваны, тоже не хорошо.
Получается нужно использовать какой то инструмент который будет отдавать задания каким сервисам создавать очередь запросов?
Какой инструмент можно использовать, чтобы обеспечить нужную гибкость?

Answer (score 1):

ИМХО: Кафка или Rabbit - это внутренние технические сервисы, которыми пользуются более высокоуровневые сервисы типа Api или приложения.

Именно на них лежит ответственность по авторизации или определении других условий допустимости транспортировки данных в системе при помощи таких низкоуровневых транспортных систем

Comment: С одним сервисом понятно, что идентификатор сервиса в url можно передавать. А вот если одновременно нужно вызвать 2 и более сервиса, то по url уже не получиться так сделать. Вот как сделать?

Comment: А почему вы не хотите напрямую к сервисам обращаться, используя http или grpc?

Comment: напрямую т.е. без использования очередей на Кафка или Rabbit? А если сервис вышел из строя, тогда без очередей будет потеря данных? Например создаётся заказ Сервис Склада вышел из строя и списал из наличия товар для заказа, а Сервис Логистики лег и не записал данные о заказе. И при обращении напрямую к сервисам потерю данных врятли получится избежать

Comment: Тогда из вашего вопроса не понятна суть задачи. Если клиент создает заказ, то он может подождать пока все сервисы отработают, а если один из сервисов сломался и не отвечает, то придется ждать, когда его восстановят. В этом случаи ожидание будет большим. Что тогда видит пользователь в браузере?

Comment: Клиент может подождать, но может получится что он не дождется и данные заказа потеряются. Либо допустим один сервис отработал , вроде как всё ок заказ принят. А сервис Логистики был недоступен и ничего не записал и логисты не узнали о том что пользователь сделал заказ и заказ не обработан

Comment: graphQL оказывается умеет запросы по микросервисам распределять. Только не могу найти информацию как связать его с кафкой или раббитом